# How to create date in MySQL from 'year' and 'month' values taken from different rows of the table and use it in 'where' clause

Tags: mysql

In MySQL database I have table *item* with some columns describing items, and another table *itemExtendedFields*. The second one has columns: *id, itemId, name, value*. In the *itemExtendedFields* additional information about items are stored.

Some items have expiry date that can be constructed from two values kept in two rows of *itemExtendedFields* table.
For example for an item with *itemId* = 34 i have following two rows in *itemExtendedFields*:

`id | itemId | name | value`

`--------------------------`

`87 | 34 | ExpiryYear | 2014`

`88 | 34 | ExpiryMonth | 2`

I need to write query that selects all items from *items* along with *expiryYear* and *ExpiryMonth* values from *itemExtendedFields* table in separate columns. Moreover i need to select items that will expire on given date (for example February 2014). I have no idea how to construct proper query. I cannot change the construction of the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will list all columns from `items` table along with the `ExpiryYear` and `ExpiryMonth` from the `itemExtendedFields` table.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.ExpiryYear, b.ExpiryMonth
FROM    items a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  itemID,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'ExpiryYear' THEN `value` ELSE NULL END) ExpiryYear,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'ExpiryMonth' THEN `value` ELSE NULL END) ExpiryMonth 
            FROM    itemExtendedFields
            GROUP BY itemID
        ) b ON a.itemID = b.itemID
WHERE   b.ExpiryYear = 2012 AND 
        b.ExpiryMonth = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly clear what you are trying to do but since you have the values in a single column, it might be easier to *pivot* the data in the `itemExtendedFields` table first, then filter similar to this:

```
select *
from
(
    select i.id,
        MAX(case when f.name = 'ExpiryYear' then f.value end) ExpiryYear,
        MAX(case when f.name = 'ExpiryMonth' then f.value end) ExpiryMonth
    from item i
    left join itemExtendedFields f
        on i.id = f.itemid
    group by i.id
) src
where ExpiryYear = 2014
    and ExpiryMonth = 2
```

This *pivoting* is taking the values which are stored in a single column/multiple rows and places it into multiple columns with a single row.  It might be possible to add more columns from the `item` table to the subquery or you can join this subquery back to the `item` table to get the additional details.

Similar to this:

```
select *
from item i
left join 
(
    select f.itemid,
        MAX(case when f.name = 'ExpiryYear' then f.value end) ExpiryYear,
        MAX(case when f.name = 'ExpiryMonth' then f.value end) ExpiryMonth
    from itemExtendedFields f
    group by f.itemid
) src
   on i.id = src.itemid
where src.ExpiryYear = 2014
    and src.ExpiryMonth = 2
```

Comment: from your updated answer. the extra join from `item` table isn't necessary. it will have cost you extra resources because you are already joining it from the topmost query.

Comment: great explaination, as always `+1` :D happy new year!

Comment: @JW. thanks you too.  You confuse me since you keep changing your name on SO. :)

Comment: this will be the last time `:D`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ItemId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'ExpiryYear' THEN value END) ExpiryYear,
       MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'ExpiryMonth' THEN value END) ExpiryMonth
FROM itemExtendedFields
GROUP BY itemId
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7101a/1)